# Does a live electrical wire change the surrounding atmospheric chemistry?

Tags: atmospheric-chemistry

**Background:** I'm world building an Earth-like world for a writing project. One of the goals of this project is to talk about changes in atmospheric chemistry across multiple scales ('nano'-scale through the entire atmospheric air column). My project has a scientist-type character to describe how atmospheric chemistry is affected by different processes. Example: Oxygen is released from leaves during the day, and carbon dioxide is released from leaves at night. Inversion layers occur regularly through the day-night cycle. Altitude impacts the density of air.

Here, I'm curious about the intersection of electricity and atmospheric chemical makeup.

**Question:** What chemical changes to atmospheric nitrogen and oxygen would/wouldn't occur in the presence of a wire carrying a current (not insulated)? (if any) Put another way, is the chemistry of the air around a live wire different in any way, shape, or form to the chemistry of the air around a wire with no current?

My internet research indicates a few possibilities but I'm not getting a firm sense of the reliability of the results. Example: Maybe ozone is produced by an electrical charge, or maybe it isn't - there seems to be conflicting ideas out there.

Here are some ideas I've seen:

- charged particles in the air might naturally gravitate differently towards/away from an electrical current? This would be a change in the movement of existing molecules, perhaps physics rather than chemistry.
- dinitrogen and dioxygen might become charged species (will these be positive or negative charges? Is the charge lost easily?
- ozone might form?
- Other species might form? nitrogen oxide species?

**My best estimates for the current are:**

~10000 volts and 120 milliamps in one portion of the writing project (electric fence); 120 volts and 20 amps in another portion (electrical cord.) I have some latitude here but those are ballpark estimates.

Comment: How much current are you talking about?